# Using OAuth 2.0 with C#

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0

Is it possible to receive an OAuth 2.0 access token from a REST API and trigger the request by using this token only by using plain .Net? Or do i have to use third party libraries to face this problem?

I found several examples but so far it isn't clear to me whether i can handle it just with .Net.

I'm in a .Net console application. It's a so called REST exporter. The process is already able to request a token but so far only with  http basic authentication. Now i have the need to request a token over OAuth 2.0.

Thanks for any Help.

Comment: Following uses Newton JSON library : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/shopping-content/code-example-authentication-oauth#part-two-code-grant-flow-implementation  This link uses just Microsoft libraries : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services#create-a-sample-web-application

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with "plain .Net"? What framework? What packages? What versions? What language even?! I've never heard of anything like "plain .Net"...

Comment: @JHBonarius Okay sorry for the confusion. I use C# and .Net 4.5.2. What i mean is, can it be done with classes like HttpWebRequest without tons of extra code for example? I think basically it can be implemented with C# so the question is more about the time it would takes. So are there classes like HttpWebRequest available in .Net which will already do the trick in the main parts for me or is it a huge effort to implement it by my own without using third party libraries?

Comment: @jdweng mmh okay from what i see in your first example it can be done with HttpWebRequest. But i wonder whether that's all. I can see nothing special just an Http request and some specific body params and that's all?

Comment: Looks like first example is going to a website to get the token.